# How to make a report using crystal report that links foreign key and primary key in one table

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports, foreign-keys, report, primary-key

I am new in crystal report. I want to make a report that display all the list of staff, but I'm stuck. I want to know how can I display Manager Name Column. I used sql server and my primary key is staff_id the foreign key constraint is manager_id that references in staff_id. I attach my screenshot. Thanks you

Answer (score 0):

In Database Expert, add the same table a 2nd time. Crystal would give that new instance of the table an Alias. You can rename it (e.g. 'Manager').
Now simply join the Employee table and the Manager alias table.